# set alpha background image iphone application in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, background, alpha

I got this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png" ]];
```

and some other stuff like textfields and stuff on one view.

I want to set the backgroundimages alpha so that it doesnt distract.
but when i do:

```
self.view.alpha
```

it sets it for all objects :-(

and there is no:

```
self.view.backgroundcolor.alpha
```

any idea?

Comment: what actually want to do? make it clear.

Comment: have a background for my applicationwindow with the alpha setting set to some value...

"I want to set the backgroundimages alpha so that it doesnt distract. but when i do:"

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out so that you don't need 2 separate views.

```
    // Make sure your whole view is NOT transparent
    self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
    // Use UIColor to set alpha transparency of just the background view
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5f];
```

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works. To achieve the effect you desire, you need two separate views, one that contains just the background (and has its `alpha` set), and one with a transparent background and `alpha` of 1.0 that contains the other controls.

Comment: how can I view two views at the same time...?

Comment: Create both views and add them as subviews to your view controller's main view (you can do that in IB or in code).

Comment: actually Im inte beginning of learning this new tools and objective-c so I havent got a clue on how to do that. I have an exampleproject that I am making changes in. There are 4 classfiles already in the project and Im not sure wich is subview and wich is not. and do I need a xib for the backgroundimage?
hope you can help a noob